# Ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainList extends ListFragment {

    public final static String TAG = MainList.class.getSimpleName();
    private ParallaxListView list;
    private Context context;



    String[] itemname = new String[]{
            " ",
            " ",
            " "
    };

    Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.osnova,
            R.drawable.osnova,
            R.drawable.osnova
    };

    String[] opisanie = new String[]{
            " ",
            " ".
            " "
    };

    public static MainList newInstance() {
        return new MainList();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
        list = (ParallaxListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_photoshop);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

list.setHeaderDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_3ds));


        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;

    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] itemname;
        private final Integer[] imgid;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
            super(context, R.layout.listview_item, itemname);

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context=context;
            this.itemname=itemname;
            this.imgid=imgid;
        }

        public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null,true);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            extratxt.setText(" Описание: "+ opisanie[position]);
            return rowView;

        };
}}
```

Вылетает ошибка вот тут: `list.setHeaderDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_3ds));`

Стектрейс:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void by.sviter.allbestlessons.ui.ParallaxListView.setHeaderDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
            at by.sviter.allbestlessons.listadapter.MainListPhotoshop.onCreateView(MainListPhotoshop.java:286)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если перегружаете `onCreateView` для `ListFragment`, то необходимо самостоятельно загружать разметку из xml.  Пример:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
        list = (ParallaxListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_photoshop);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        list.setHeaderDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_3ds));
        return v;
    }
```